# Python os spawn does not work with google chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, spawn

This works as expected:

```
import os
ls = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\git\\bin\\ls.exe'
os.spawnl(os.P_NOWAIT, ls, 'C:\\')
```

I can use chrome from the command line like so, and http://example.com loads fine:

```
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe" http://example.com
```

This spawns chrome, but does not load http://example.com

```
import os
chrome = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'
os.spawnl(os.P_NOWAIT, chrome, 'http://example.com')
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If chrome is your default browser, you could use the `webbrowser` module.

```
import webbrowser 

# For Windows
webbrowser.get("windows-default").open("http://example.com")

# For Mac
webbrowser.get("macosx").open("http://example.com")
```

Comment: Opens in firefox, even though google chrome is my default browser.

Comment: Python 3: `webbrowser.get('chrome').open('http://example.com')` throws an error. :(